# Importing Pygame: Strange DLL Error

Tags: python

I've recently downloaded Pygame for the first time on this computer. When I try to run a script that uses "import pygame" it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "graphs.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message almost always implies you are using an extension module containing a compiled DLL for a 64-bit version of Python but you're running a 32-bit version of Python. Or vice-versa.

Comment: Hmm so I must have downloaded the 64 bit version of python by mistake. Thanks.